# Extract innermost lists from n-dimensional jagged array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to parse a jagged, n-dimensional list of lists (of lists, etc.). For instance, for an array `a`, if `len(a) = 3`, then the lengths of the lists it contains could be: `len(a[0]) = 5`, `len(a[1]) = 8`, and `len(a[2]) = 5`. Then each of the five lists in `a[0]` could also be of different lengths, as could the eight lists in `a[1]` and the five lists in `a[2]`. This nesting continues for some arbitrary depth `n`, but this depth is consistent everywhere. Also, the innermost objects of this structure are lists of constant length—for the sake of example, say they're all `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I am currently using a recursive solution, something like:

```
def flatten_to_2d(a):
    if all(isinstance(n, list) for n in a):
        if len(a) > 1:
            return flatten_to_2d(a[0]) + flatten_to_2d(a[1:len(a)])
        else:
            return flatten_to_2d(a[0])
    else:
        return [a]
```

but have had this exceed Python's default recursion depth for large inputs (e.g., 50*`x`*4, where x is between about 1000 and 1500 for different lists in the array's second dimension). It is easy enough to increase this with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, but is there a better/more Pythonic way to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You test if all elements of `a` are lists, but isn't it enough to just test the first element? As for your question: yes, pretty much any problem that can be solved recursively, can also be solved iteratively. Are you simply throwing out all structure and do you want to end up with a single list of lists (i.e. just the innermost objects)?

Comment: @Grismar yes, exactly – the final structure I'm looking for is just a list of all the innermost lists (which are slightly more interesting than [1, 2, 3, 4], but same idea). Also you're right, given the constraints I mentioned, the first element could be used to determine whether max depth has been reached yet. I'd really appreciate it if you could share the iterative approach you're thinking of!

Comment: Does `[[],[]]` have depth 1, such that the return value should also be `[[],[]]`, or does it have depth greater than 1, such that the return value should be `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 generators make this quite easy.  If you know the **depth**, you can write

```
def lists(xx,n):
  if n:
    for x in xx: yield from lists(x,n-1)
  else: yield xx
```

Alternatively, if you know the innermost lists are **non-empty** (so that they can be recognized by containing a non-list), you can write

```
def lists(xx):
  if xx and not isinstance(xx[0],list): yield xx
  else:
    for x in xx: yield from lists(x)
```

If you know neither of these, the problem is ill-formed in general (although it can be solved in most cases by finding a non-list element to discover the depth).

Comment: The second case is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! The given is that all innermost lists are non-empty (and of constant length).

Comment: If this solves your problem, that's great - it's still recursive though, so if your data structures were exceeding recursion limits previously, they're likely to still do that (unless your previous solution had needless additional recursion). If you're after a solution that actually avoids recursion, look at my answer.

Comment: @Grismar: The approach in the question was recursive in the *length* of the lists, which is categorically different.  (It also did not ask for a non-recursive approach.)

Comment: You're right - poor reading on my part. I'll leave the answer for who makes the same mistake, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting the unpacking of nested lists of lists. The nesting continues for some arbitrary number of levels n, but the same number of levels for all lists.

The unpacking should result in a single list of all the lists at level n in the nested structure.

Based on your example, n isn't given up front, but should should be determined by examining the nested list being unpacked.

A solution:

```
def unpack_fixed_depth(xs):
    # find depth n of nested lists xs
    ys = xs
    depth = -2
    while isinstance(ys, list):
        ys = ys[0]
        depth += 1

    c = 0
    positions = [iter(xs)] + [None] * depth
    while c >= 0:
        while 0 <= c < depth:
            try:
                positions[c+1] = iter(next(positions[c]))
                c += 1
            except StopIteration:
                c -= 1
        if c >= 0:
            for item in positions[c]:
                yield item
            c -= 1


print(list(unpack_fixed_depth([[1, 2], [3, 4]])))
print(list(unpack_fixed_depth([[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6]]], [[[7, 8]]], [[[7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]]])))
```

Result:

```
print(list(unpack_fixed_depth([[1, 2], [3, 4]])))
print(list(unpack_fixed_depth([[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6]]], [[[7, 8]]], [[[7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]]])))
```

Of course, if some of the assumptions are wrong (for example, not every nesting is equally deep, you'd need to change the solution.